# Nodejs websocket request to php

Tags: php, node.js

I have a Nodejs websocket that forward incoming request to php.

How to know if this php call are going outside the server or it is internally?

Server has more than one Domain: [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) and [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com)

websocket call to php:

```
phpURL = 'https://www.example1.com/sub/function.php';

var options = {
  method: 'post',
  body: param, 
  json: true, 
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: false,
  agent: false,
  url: phpURL,
  headers: {
     
    'Cookie': ck
  }
}

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
 
        try{  
            var allReq = body.split("------");
            for(var i=0;i<allReq.length;i++){
                ws.send(allReq[i]);  
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log('Error :', e)
            return; 
        }

    });
```

The php call normally is fast but sometime
get slow.
Apache take time to accept the request.

Comment: You have no ability from this code to know anything about what the PHP server is or isn't doing with your request.  If you control the PHP code, then you can debug it directly and see what it's doing for your request.

Comment: I debug it and it shows internal server IP.

Answer (score 0):

The request was going out to resolve the DNS.

I managed to avoid the request going out to resolve.
Setting the domain in the Host file to local.
And removing the WWW from the request.